# listen for stream and print value in dart main function

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, dart-stream

I want to print `data.length` after listening to this `stream` but the program executed synchronously. How can I listen to this data stream without using the `await-for` syntax

```dart
void main() async {
  final file = File('assets/text_long.txt');
  final stream = file.openRead();

  stream.listen(
    (data) {
      print(data.length);
    },
  );
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Exited (1)
```

Comment: await didn't work: Uses 'await' on an instance of 'StreamSubscription<dynamic>', which is not a subtype of 'Future'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asFuture` method.

```
  final file = File('assets/text_long.txt');
  final stream = file.openRead();

  final streamSubscription = stream.listen(
    (data) {
      print(data.length);
    },
  );
  await streamSubscription.asFuture();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use await keyword.

```
await stream.listen(
    (data) {
      print(data.length);
    },
  );
```

Comment: It didn't work : Uses 'await' on an instance of 'StreamSubscription<dynamic>', which is not a subtype of 'Future'.